# External storage of patterns for SpaCy matchers

Tags: python, spacy

A SpaCy matcher can hold more then one pattern (https://spacy.io/api/matcher). To better organize my patterns for SpaCy matchers I would like to store them in a database (e.g., SQLite). Is this possible? How can I load them into the matcher?

As I understand it, patterns are organized in a list of list that contain dictionaries. So, could store the name of the pattern, the key and the value in a database table. Then loop through these and build the pattern. The problem arises when I would like to use value that are key value pairs themselves, e.g. with a pattern like '{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "[a-z][A-Z]?"}}'. Is there a better way to organize, control and store patterns for matchers (e.g., avoid duplicates or patterns that could easily be merged)?

Comment: Please show what you've done so far.

Comment: Patterns are just simple json-friendly structures so you can save them anywhere as text. You would just load them from the DB and deserialize the JSON. Not sure what your question is?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.